# logger cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

```
package automationTester;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class LoggingDemo1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\eruma\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        **logger log =Logger.getLogger("devpinoyLogger");**
```

Comment: Edit your question with exact issue, error you received after running your code to avoid flagging your question by someone.. posting only code doesn't mean to understand everything what you want.

Comment: Have you checked your Java build path and include the following jar file into the libraries slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar and slf4j-simple-1.7.7.jar and the code should have  import org.apache.log4j.Logger instead of import java.util.logging.Logger .Hope this change will solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
logger log =Logger.getLogger("devpinoyLogger");
```

Should be

```
Logger log =Logger.getLogger("devpinoyLogger");
```

Classes are started from the uppercase in Java. However you can name your class from the lowercase (if you are not aware of Java coding conventions), but `logger` and `Logger` would be two different classes.